Angular Always redirecting to default path:
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "admin_login", component: AdminLoginComponent },
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "owner", component: OwnerComponent },
  { path: "admin", component: AdminComponent },
  { path: "decor", component: DecorComponent },
  { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: "", component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
];


This is my app-routing.module.ts
How is it possible that whichever route I enter here, it redirects me to the default path, but when I have a routerLink to a component it redirects me well.
I have consulted all sorts of AI but every time we go in circles.
What could be the issue?
I can drop any Angular file if needed

Code snippet is useless, do you have a stackblitz prepared?

There's no default aka wildcard route set there! (see here about wildcard routes: https://angular.dev/guide/routing/common-router-tasks#setting-up-wildcard-routes) . Which is the default path you're referring to? Also, could you share an example of a route that you visit, the actual result and the expect result? Thanks!

Please use the following code in your app.module.ts file.
If you want to redirect to the AdminLoginComponent when the application starts, please use the redirect concept:
const routes: Routes = [
      { path: "admin_login", component: AdminLoginComponent },
      { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
      { path: "owner", component: OwnerComponent },
      { path: "admin", component: AdminComponent },
      { path: "decor", component: DecorComponent },
      { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent },
      { path: "", redirectTo: 'admin_login', pathMatch: "full" },
    ];

